# Assign ssh users depends on host names mentioned in host file in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My Host file is defined as below.

```
[groupname]
server1
server2
server3
```

Each server from the above list have different SSH user to logins.

In my playbook I am setting up the user depending on the hostname condition.

```
- name: setting user user1
  set_fact: ssh_user='user1'
  when: "{{ inventory_hostname }}" == 'server1'

- name: setting user user2
  set_fact: ssh_user='user2'
  when: "{{ inventory_hostname }}" == 'server2'

- name: setting user user3
  set_fact: ssh_user='user3'
  when: "{{ inventory_hostname }}" == 'server3'
```

However this is not working as expected, and always throwing a syntax error, but the yaml is valid.

Looking for some suggestion.

Below is the Error thrown when the playbook executes,

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
The error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/_2573__sample/mysample.yml': line 6, column 36, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
  set_fact: ssh_user='user1'
  when: "{{ inventory_hostname }}" == 'server1'
                                   ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value.
```

Comment: 1. You are talking about an error your are getting. Please edit your question and add the error. 2. You are totally misusing ansible. You should set your ssh user in the `remote_user` variable [inside your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#host-variables)

Comment: 1. Added the error in the question.
2. I am not sure what do you mean by "misusing ansible" - I am already assigning the remote_user: '{{ ssh_user }}' at the below in my playbook, I haven't copied my entire playbook in the question section. May be that made you to think like that.

Comment: By 2 point Zeitounator meant that you can define the users in the respective group vars you don't need to use set_fact especially for specificiying the user name. And for the error can you try using "" instead of ' pls

Answer (score 1):

The `when` clause in a task is not supposed to be a jinja2 expanded var. Use

```
when: inventory_hostname == 'somehost'
```

Moreover, regarding my previous comment, there is no use to set fact as you do in your playbook for such a variable. You shoud set this at inventory level so you don't have to bother for whatever playbook you use. You have several options for that. If you want to stick to your ini style inventory, you could do it like this:

```
[groupname]
server1 ansible_user=user1
server2 ansible_user=user2
server3 ansible_user=user3
```

You can also make your inventory in yaml, or declare the host variables in separate files (in `host_vars/<hostname>.yml`). You should [read the doc about inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) to get familiar with those concepts.